# How to pass custom parameters to sendy via node js api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sendy

I am trying to pass custom data in sendy via api of sendy. Sendy has custom field attributes in which we can pass data. I am using a sendy node js package whose link is provided on sendy website. the issue is that i am not able to pass custom field data to sendy api. Here is my code

```
 var params = {
            email: email2,
            custom: {
                'assignmentDetail':assignmentLink,
                'submissionDetail':submissionDetail,
                'FormLink':reviewerFormLink,
            },
            list_id: ListID,
            api_key: 'vQzxtX76pNFekG4w5BzC'
        };
        sendy.subscribe(params, function (err, result) {  if (err){ 
                console.log(err.toString());
                }else{ 
                UpdateData(recordID, email2, ListID);     
                console.log('Subscribed succesfully');}
            });
```

the custom field data is not being passed in the sendy. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. It is very simple. You need to make your custom fields in enclosed in quotes and you are done. Just like this

```
 var params = {
            email: email2,
         //make sure custom field names are same otherwise sendy would igore the fields
                'assignmentDetail':assignmentLink,
                'submissionDetail':submissionDetail,
                'FormLink':reviewerFormLink,
            
            list_id: ListID,
            api_key: 'vQzxtX76pNFekG4w5BzC'
        };
        sendy.subscribe(params, function (err, result) {  if (err){ 
                console.log(err.toString());
                }else{ 
                UpdateData(recordID, email2, ListID);     
                console.log('Subscribed succesfully');}
            });
```